# Lombok Not Working For Eclipse 2023 and STS

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I've tried most steps suggested by folks out here and I'm unable to install Lombok.

How my eclipse.ini looks:

```
-vmargs
..
..
..
-Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/rafaellima/eclipse/java-2023-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
-javaagent:/Users/rafaellima/eclipse/java-2023-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

I included Xbootclasspath manually -- this makes the Lombok errors go away, but in turn breaks the build making the application unable to start with the following error:

"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'algafood-api'.
javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor"

Removing Xbootclasspath makes the build error go away, but then makes Lombok not work.

I've also tried running the GUI installed and selecting the eclipse.ini, but that does not include the Xbootclasspath.

I've spent countless hours on this without a solution.

I'm running Mac High Sierra 10.13.6.

Eclipse : Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) Build id: 20231201-2043

Lombok Version : 1.18.8

Also does not work with STS, similar issues.

Please HEEEEEELPPPP

Comment: Always, *always* makes sure you're trying it with the latest Lombok release. You are currently not.

Comment: [Lombok 1.18.8 has been released on May 7, 2019](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/releases/tag/v1.18.8) and is probably too old. The current Lombok version is 1.18.30 (released on September 20, 2023), still older than Eclipse 2023-12: see [Lombok issues #3564](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3564).

Comment: That worked you guys. I'm not sure how I ended up with an older version. Maybe through some IDE market place or something!!!

You guys are awesome. Can someone move it to the answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, *always* makes sure you're trying it with the latest Lombok release. 1.18.8 is not the latest.